# setting custom path in routeconfig.cs in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

Below is my routeconfig.cs file in mvc4 application

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{bizId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", bizId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Outlet",
            "Outlet/{bizId}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            new { bizId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

When i run the application, i need to enter /Home/Index?bizId=1 or any Id after the localhost port to run my application. It is working fine. But, now as the second route.maproute, I want the url to show as for ex: localhost:49787/Outlet?bizId=1 but this doesnt work. Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Try placing your second route in first place

Answer (score 2):

got the fix:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Outlet",
            url: "Outlet/{bizId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", bizId = 1 }
        );
```