# Template name automatically bind when Binding Images in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, xslt, umbraco

I am new in the Umbraco. i am having problem when binding the images using an XSLT file here is my XSLT file. I am using Umbraco 6.1.6

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="minLevel" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage">
    <div class="divHouseEmployeeList">
         <img src="{concat('..', ./employeePhoto)}" />
        <!--<img src="{./employeePhoto}" alt="{./employeeName}" />
        <img src="{concat('..',./employeePhoto)}" alt="{./employeeName}" />-->


        <xsl:value-of select="concat('..', ./employeePhoto)"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor::* [@level &gt; $minLevel]">
            <xsl:if test="./houseSymbol != '' ">
                <img src="{concat('..',substring-before(./houseSymbol,'.'), '_thumb.jpg')}" alt="" class="staticImageStyle" />  
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </div>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Here I am binding the detail of the Current Page and One of the detail of its previous Page. XSLT file is save successfully but when i am configured with the IIS images are not showing Check out snap below which shows Error in the Firebug

```
URL : http://localhost/WebPortalUmb/houses/trident/csah.aspx
```

[image: Houses Error Screen]

As you can see in the Snap there are houses that is Template name and WebPortalUmb that is Application Name in the IIS.

Also You can see when loading the Home Page then Application Name is missing that i have noticed from Firebug. Check out the Snap below of the HomePage.

```
URL : http://localhost/WebPortalUmb/home.aspx
```

[image: Home Page Error Screen]

I am new in umbraco so please help in in it. I have also bind the URL so that you can understand the Issue. Please Comment if you have any problem in the Question.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154360/umbraco-can-get-text-but-not-image-from-a-subnode-to-homepage

Comment: Thanks for the Reply but none of this works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the media images is well documented (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getmedia) so rendering them out of xslt is simple enough.

If you're using Umbraco 6.1.6 then I assume that you are using MVC - if so all the 404s being thrown are probably happening because your mvc routing is not setting your relative position in the hierarchy where you are expecting.

Your /houses/scripts references will only work if you have your scripts under a folder called houses (which you say is your template (controller???)).  I would guess that two things will get you into a better place.

Firstly change all your script references to have a leading slash ie /WebPortalUmb/scripts - this will force the scripts to go to the correct place regardless of absolute/relative position of the calling page/view/whatever.

Secondly put some debugging break points into your routing tables (eg /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) so that you can see which controller action will be hit each time ([setting custom path in routeconfig.cs in mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835848/setting-custom-path-in-routeconfig-cs-in-mvc-4))

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but having one more issue.. When configure Umbraco App with IIS. I can't see the Application name that you can see in the 2nd Image. Is there any solution of this Issues ??